# How to count the number of dynamic nested arrays in laravel dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, count, nested

```
{
    "name" : "lv0",
    "children" : [
       {
           "name" : "lv1",
           "children" : [
                {
                    "name" : "lv2",
                    "children" : [
                        {
                            "name" : "lv3"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
       }
    ]
}
```

this is the json and I only wants to count the number of children's array, I am using this code:

```
$data[] = $request->children;
    $count = 0;
    foreach($data as $data){
        $count++;
    }
    return $count;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know how many nested children, you should use `while` loop:

```php
$data = json_decode('{
    "name" : "lv0",
    "children" : [
       {
           "name" : "lv1",
           "children" : [
                {
                    "name" : "lv2",
                    "children" : [
                        {
                            "name" : "lv3"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
       }
    ]
}');
$child = $data;
$count = 0;
while (property_exists($child, 'children')) {
    $count++;
    $child = $child->children[0];
}
echo $count;
```

Ouput:

```php
3
```

Comment: it is working but 
$data = json_decode('{
    "name" : "lv0",
    "children" : [
       {
           "name" : "lv1",
           "children" : [
                {
                    "name" : "lv2",
                    "children" : [
                        {
                            "name" : "lv3"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
       }
    ]
}'); 
this part is not for me how can i do this for request case?

Comment: Since I don't know what your input looks like, I have assumed `$data` according to your question using `json_decode`

Comment: inputs are the same as provided in json

Comment: If the data in your request is already an object, just replace it for `$data`

Comment: public function createTree($request)
    {
        // this is the function 
    }

Comment: can you please complete it

Comment: Please clearly describe `$request` in your question. You can debug or use `var_dump()` to get it. I will update my answer base on it.

Comment: $request is all json that i recvd from postman

Comment: Is your `$request` an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request`? If it is, you can retrieve data by `$data = $request->input('abc');` with `abc` is name of data you post to your API from Postman.

Comment: public function createTree($request)
    {
        $json = json_encode($request->all(), true);
        $child = $json;
        $count = 0;
        while (property_exists($child, 'children')) {
            $count++;
            $child = $child->children[0];
        }
        echo $count;
    }
i am using this and in my json i have 2 childs but this give me result as zero

Comment: Why do you use `json_encode()`? That would make `$json` a string, and thus result would be 0. Make sure `$json` is a JSON object like the input you described in your question

Comment: when i use json_decode it gives me this error "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: I am not telling you to use `json_decode()`. `$request->all()` returns an array of inputs from the request. Get the one you need and assign it to `$json`

Comment: Please read my previous comments again. And you also need to read more about [retrieving input from request](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input)  in Laravel

Comment: when i use request->children it gives me all childrens how can I iterate each children dynamically